# How to use content query webpart to filter by custom people column?

Tags: search, content-query-web-part, managed-property, crawled-property

I'm trying to set up the content query webpart on portal level (site collection) to retrieve a list of tasks, where the current user is set to the responsible person. Notice that the responsible person is not the  field.

**What I did/what I tried:**

1. Created a site column named  of type "person or group"
2. Added site column to a task list on a sub site and entered some data
3. mapped the managed property  to the crawled property
4. set up content query search with the query:

   `ContentTypeId:0x0108*  responsibleOWS={User.Name}`

Unfortunatelly the query returns no results. Troubleshooting steps so far:

1. requested re-indexing of sub site
2. created new manual managed property
3. compared values in managed property and crawled property with the values from field
4. Added  to the result view (values are shown correctly)
5. Went to "test" tab on query editor, entered different values for user.name manually -> no result :(

Oh please, can someone give me advise how to finish these things.

Best Regards

Timo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use `responsibleOWS:{User.Name}` instead of `responsibleOWS={User.Name}`

Comment: Great. It works with the operator  ":" now. I am not sure if I realy missed training the contains clause, but now it works! Many many thx :)